# Bluetooth scanning with app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, scanning

I am making an app and was wondering does my app need to scan for Bluetooth devices? Because the phone itself already scans for devices.

Do I need to setup a scanner in my app to be able to use Bluetooth efficiently?
Or can i utilize the "scanner" from my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you do not need to write your own. Android has it's own discovery functionality built into the BluetoothAdapter class that you can utilize.

Check out this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-androids-bluetooth-api--cms-24084

Comment: Oke, so i still need to scan for devices that my phone already scanned?

Comment: Yes, you can get a list of bonded devices, which are devices that your phone has previously paired to. Again I recommend checking the link above.

Comment: I read it, let me rephrase my comment.  When you go to your Bluetooth setting, you can scan for devices that have Bluetooth on, for example other mobile phones etc. Is it possible to use those scanned devices? Not the paired one but the ones that the mobile just discovered.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13665063)

Comment: @RamenChef I understand what you are saying, however I did answer the question. The OP asked if he needed to set up a scanner, I answered the questions and then provided supporting materials. The OP did not ask "how".